# jQuery Ajax success function not being called in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap Modal form to check IMO's Existence and I am using jQuery Ajax Post to submit it.

```js
$('#submitCheck').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Entry/Index",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
       alert("Check");
       if (data == 'true') {
         alert("RETURN TRUE");
         window.location.href = "/Entry/Create";
       } else {
         alert("RETURN FALSE");
         $('#divStat').html("IMO does not exist");
       }

     },
     error: function() {
       alert("Something went wrong");
     }
   });
 })
```

And here is Controller:

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string IMO) {
  var data = db.Ships.Where(d => d.IMO.Equals(IMO)).FirstOrDefault();
  if (data != null)
    return Json(true);
  return Json(false);
}
```

When I submit form, IMO was checked and I watched result is 'true' (or 'false') on View, but in jQuery Code, success function is not being called, so I can't see 'alert' or anything else.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried looking at it using a JavaScript debugger? Not sure what browser your using, but that might be a good place to start. See if it is throwing any type of error.

Comment: I used Firebug to check 'data', but I watch nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check for the string 'true' or the boolean true? If you remove the quotes this should evaluate to true.
Also, you might want to do something like this:
 `return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` so you can do:

```
success: function (data) {
            //or if(data.success) which evaluates to true.
            if (data.success == true) {
                alert("RETURN TRUE");
            }
```

Comment: I have tried like your idea, but I'm not receive nothing from Server, After submitting form, Page direct to .../Entry/Index, and Page get result:
{"success":true}